# How can I utilize werkzeug.security's check_password_hash function to verify correct password against existing salted sha1 password hashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I'm working on a new python application for work that needs to verify existing user credentials in our database. Many of our relic applications were built on PHP's Symfony framework, which is where these password hashes and salts would have originated from. In the database the algorithm (sha1), the salt & the hashed password for users is retained. I'm trying to figure out how to correctly verify a password using this information in conjuncture the `check_password_hash` function of the `werkzeug.security` module. However, so far I've been unsuccessful.

For demonstration purposes I've created a test user and the database contains the following values for the user.

#### Test user values

`algorithm`: sha1
`salt`: e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c
`password` (hashed): 784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b

The ***actual* password** of the test user is 123456

### I've tried the following methods to verify the password.

**Notes:**
1. Hash format was adapted from the [werkzeug.security](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash) documentation
2. Comparative Hash method was adapted from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53059134/2962937)

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash

# Attempt 1 - Results in False
check_password_hash('sha1$e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c$784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b','123456')

# Attempt 2 - Results in False
check_password_hash('pbkdf2:sha1$e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c$784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b','123456')

# Attempt 3
# Step 1: Append the salt_value to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
generate_password_hash('123456$e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c','sha1')
# sha1$9lUceSsd$60f7dcb3ff9c22d4613e59fcbfed0c463ee4189e
# Step 2: Compare the hash to the hash in the database
# 60f7dcb3ff9c22d4613e59fcbfed0c463ee4189e != 784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b

# Attempt 4 - Same steps as Attempt 3 except adding salt_length argument
# Step 1: Append the salt_value to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.  
generate_password_hash('123456$e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c','sha1',len('e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c'))
# sha1$EbPv6DP0wMyu02UpA6ZYazFvvYvZTVI1$b8252583fea027d42af20c0d0f3eac3fbf468bd1
# Step 2: Compare the hash to the hash in the database
# b8252583fea027d42af20c0d0f3eac3fbf468bd1 != 784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b
```

Can anyone provide some insight on what I'm doing wrong? Should I try using a different library like `passlib`? I was hoping that this module would suffice since I'm familiar with it, having created a few of our existing python applications that utilize it for *new* user sign-ups, but in a separate database.

#### Edit - To show an alternative method to using `werkzeug.security`'s `check_password_hash` function

```
import hashlib
# hashlib.sha1('{salt}{pw}'.encode()).hexdigest() == {pw_hash}
hashlib.sha1('e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c123456'.encode()).hexdigest() == '784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b'
# True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`werkzeug.generate_password_hash` wants to generate a salt value. Taking a look at the source we can see `_hash_internal` called with the generated salt value.

```
def generate_password_hash(password, method="pbkdf2:sha256", salt_length=8):
    """Hash a password with the given method and salt with a string of
    the given length. The format of the string returned includes the method
    that was used so that :func:`check_password_hash` can check the hash.

    The format for the hashed string looks like this::

        method$salt$hash

    This method can **not** generate unsalted passwords but it is possible
    to set param method='plain' in order to enforce plaintext passwords.
    If a salt is used, hmac is used internally to salt the password.

    If PBKDF2 is wanted it can be enabled by setting the method to
    ``pbkdf2:method:iterations`` where iterations is optional::

        pbkdf2:sha256:80000$salt$hash
        pbkdf2:sha256$salt$hash

    :param password: the password to hash.
    :param method: the hash method to use (one that hashlib supports). Can
                   optionally be in the format ``pbkdf2:<method>[:iterations]``
                   to enable PBKDF2.
    :param salt_length: the length of the salt in letters.
    """
    salt = gen_salt(salt_length) if method != "plain" else ""
    h, actual_method = _hash_internal(method, salt, password)
    return "%s$%s$%s" % (actual_method, salt, h)
```

If we call `_hash_internal` with your `sha1` method, and provided salt/password, we get a different hash

```
In [83]: import werkzeug.security                                                                                                                                                     

In [84]: h, method = werkzeug.security._hash_internal('sha1', 'e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c', '123456')                                                                           

In [86]: h == '784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b'                                                                                                                              
Out[86]: False

In [85]: h                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[85]: 'e8c2de9bdc1ab92479e3e55b608a040dad7bf656'
```

I think you'll need to revisit your PHP code to see how these values are generated.

EDIT: per your comment

```
In [138]: werkzeug.security._hash_internal('sha1', '', 'e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c123456')                                                                                      
Out[138]: ('784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b', 'sha1')
```

If you want to use `check_password_hash` you'd have to not set the salt on your hash and instead prepend it to your password:

```
In [148]: werkzeug.check_password_hash('sha1$$784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b', 'e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c123456')                                                    
Out[148]: True
```

If we look at the source we can see that `check_password_hash` extracts `method`, `salt`, and `hashval` out of the `pwhash`, then validates the hashed `password` matches `hashval`. I'm not familiar with hashing in PHP, but it appears the password was "salted" and then hashed without salt (as far as werkzeug.security is concerned anyway).

```
def check_password_hash(pwhash, password):
    """check a password against a given salted and hashed password value.
    In order to support unsalted legacy passwords this method supports
    plain text passwords, md5 and sha1 hashes (both salted and unsalted).

    Returns `True` if the password matched, `False` otherwise.

    :param pwhash: a hashed string like returned by
                   :func:`generate_password_hash`.
    :param password: the plaintext password to compare against the hash.
    """
    if pwhash.count("$") < 2:
        return False
    method, salt, hashval = pwhash.split("$", 2)
    return safe_str_cmp(_hash_internal(method, salt, password)[0], hashval)
```

Comment: Using this simplified php code provides the correct password hash; thus, verifying the correct password. So, I have to either be doing something wrong with how I'm using the `werkzeug.security` module or I need to use a different module. `<?php $str = 'e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c'.'123456';
echo sha1 (  $str ); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I was hoping that it would be verified via the `check_password_hash` function. If I were to use your method it still requires checking the result against the password_hash. If that's the case I'd probably be better off using `hashlib` for a simple one-liner `hashlib.sha1('{salt}{pw}'.encode()).hexdigest() == {pw_hash}`

Comment: I think werkzeug is trying to force a convention on you. You could still use `check_password_hash`, but you'd have to not set the salt on your hash and instead prepend it to your password: `werkzeug.check_password_hash('sha1$$784517f57fbe61179960739e29d7ae925aa4fd5b', 'e40e1e9addc186828a5554a71527342c123456')`

Comment: Wow, that is very interesting! Thank you for pointing that out. I find it odd that it's not allowing the salt to be included in the password_hash. Please put that in your response & I can mark it as the answer :)